# Validate function returning undefined on error checking instead of true

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs

In my basic React I have the following onFormSubmit function, which checks the target inputs for email and password.

If the form is submitted without any data, then email and password are both `""`.

However the validate function returns undefined for both `emailErr` and `passwordErr`.

The logs inside of the validate function will log out nothing, but if I set break points I will see the empty `""`. Those empty strings should validate to true in the return statement, but they don't.

```
onFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const email = e.target.email.value;
    const password = e.target.password.value;

    const validate = (email, password) => {
        console.log('validate');
        console.log(' email', email);
        console.log(' password', password);
        // true means invalid
        return {
            email: email.length === 0,
            password: password.length === 0,
        };
    }

    const { emailErr, passwordErr } = validate(email, password);

    console.log('emailErr', emailErr);
    console.log('passwordErr', passwordErr);

    if (emailErr) {
        console.log('No email!');
    }
    else if (passwordErr) {
        console.log('No password');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are returning the key value pair, you need to use the same key while Destructuring

```js
// suppose you are returning this
const a = {
  emailErr: true,
  passwordErr: true
};
  
console.log('correct implementation');
const { emailErr, passwordErr } = a;
console.log(emailErr)
console.log(passwordErr)

console.log('wrong implementation');
const { email, password } = a;
console.log(email)
console.log(password)
```